# Mapbox: How to stop event propagation on full screen control

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox map which has a fullscreen control.

I want to make it dynamic so that when user-A clicks then it works as it is BUT when user-B clicks then a javascript alert comes with message like "Hello you dont have a premium account to see fullscreen. Please upgrade" and nothing happens.

How I can do it ?

```
var mapboxMap = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map-container',
        style: styleUrl,
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: zoomVal
    });
mapboxMap.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());
```

The button created by Map Library:

```
<button class="mapboxgl-ctrl-icon mapboxgl-ctrl-fullscreen" type="button" aria-label="Enter fullscreen" title="Enter fullscreen"></button>
```

Tried 1:

```
$('.mapboxgl-ctrl-fullscreen').click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   if (user == 'user-B') {
      alert('my message');
   }
})
```

2:

```
mapboxMap.on('click', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
       if (user == 'user-B') {
          alert('my message');
        }
})
```

3:

```
mapboxmap._fullscreencontrol.click(function(event) {.........})
```

4:

```
var fsc = new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl();
mapboxMap.addControl(fsc);
fsc._onClickFullscreen(function(event) {.........});
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turn out to be not possible of hijacking full screen control, instead I got some idea to create a custom control that will look like Full Screen polygon and used that:

Sharing here so that if anyone else in future can use it.

1- Created a class to support custom draw.

```
class MapboxCustomControl {
  constructor({
    className = "",
    title = "",
    eventHandler = evtHndlr
  }) {
    this._className = className;
    this._title = title;
    this._eventHandler = eventHandler;
  }

  onAdd(map) {
    this._btn = document.createElement("button");
    this._btn.className = "mapboxgl-ctrl-icon" + " " + this._className;
    this._btn.type = "button";
    this._btn.title = this._title;
    this._btn.onclick = this._eventHandler;

    this._container = document.createElement("div");
    this._container.className = "mapboxgl-ctrl-group mapboxgl-ctrl";
    this._container.appendChild(this._btn);

    return this._container;
  }
}
```

2- Added a css style class to draw a polygon shape.

```
.mapbox-gl-draw_polygon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

3- Added a function to handle my other task.

```
function openPrivacy(event) {
    if (event.type == 'click') {
        var mapWindow = window.open("/private_page/" + event_uuid +"/", "private_page", 'height=800px,width=900');
        if (window.focus) {
          mapWindow.focus()
        }
    }
}
```

4- And finally, added custom control to map.

```
const customControl = new MapboxCustomControl({
    className: "mapbox-gl-draw_polygon",
    title: "Privacy Page",
    eventHandler: openPrivacy
});
mapboxMap.addControl(customControl, "top-right");
```

Thanks for others who devoted their time on it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the button is being added by Mapbox after the initial DOM is loaded you will most likely have to attach a listener to a parent element (like `document`) and catch the events as they bubble up from whatever element you click on. You can do this quite easily with jQuery with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mapboxgl-ctrl-fullscreen', function(event) {
   if (user == 'user-B') {
      alert('my message');
   }
});
```

Further reading

- [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks, Do you know why changing alert to console.log your solution doesn't works. Event using preventDefault();.  if ("a" == 'user-B') {
                  event.preventDefault();;
                  console.log('my message');
               }

Comment: `if ("a" == 'user-B')` doesn't make sense.

Comment: hey man, that is user == 'user_B' , actually i was bypassing a condition. copy paste issue

Answer (score 1):

You could put an if/else on actually adding the control to the map. It could look something like this:

```
if (userA) {
    mapboxMap.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());
} else if (userB) {
    // do something else
} else {
    // do something with error
}
```

Comment: I dont wanna hide .. but the control will be there and another work will be done on the click . like prompting to the user

Comment: Thanks, eventually I used your concept to hide main control and add custom one as below.